# Config changes ScreenSize and Orientation stop layout changing

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I have an android layout - main.axml, which changes based on orientation. I have overriden the OnConfigurationChanged so that I can adjust the way some icons (which sit outside of this layout) look based on other criteria. I have configuration changes set to Orientation and ScreenSize, and here's my method:

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            toggle.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            animateDrawerIcon();
            FabController();
        }
```

The problem is, the layout no longer changes, it stays the same regardless of orientation, if I put SetContentView(ResourceLayout) in the method above, the layout changes but is completely empty.

I really want Android to handle the rotation/screensize change, I just want to call two functions when that happens - can anyone advise how best to do that?

Comment: maybe try adding super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);?

Comment: This is in Xamarin, base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig); is the same as what you're saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to Android to do it, then the easiest way is to define two layouts for two orientation. This is ideal if the layout in landscape is quite different from what it looks in portrait mode.

But if it is a few bits here and there, then you should detect the current orientation of the device and toggle the buttons and switches (or whatever you want to do !!!) in your `onCreate` method. In this case, you need not define multiple layouts.

For.e.g if you have a button which you want to be only in `portrat` mode, then let the button be visible by default and in `onCreate` of your `Activity`, detect the orientation by - `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` and if the orientation is `landscape` then just toggle it.

Although `OnConfigurationChanged` method is really convinient, Avoid putting a lot of logic in it. Try either of the approaches mentioned above

Comment: I can do that, in onCreate, the problem is that the visibility state of the buttons (in your example) depends on an integer (reflects the nav drawer selected position) which is reset to -1 when I rotate the screen (I don't know why that is)

Comment: My override of the OnSavedInstanceState was wrong, corrected now, all working. Thanks

Comment: Great. That was supposed to be my next comment. `onSavedInstance` to save your UI state.